# Increase a counter in parent when a child is added in has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a schema where `User` has many `Student` with a `user_id` field.

In the `User` table, I am saving a counter `next_student_number` with default value as `1`, and there is a `roll_number` column in `Student`.

In the `Student` class, I have `before_create :generate_roll_number` callback which sets the student's roll number to `next_student_number` and increments the value in `User` class.

Some thing like this :-

```
def generate_roll_number
  self.roll_number = user.next_roll_number
  user.increment! :next_roll_number
end
```

I feel there will be an issue when two records are trying to save at the same time here. Either they'll have a clash, or some roll numbers will be skipped.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: use optimistic locking?
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html

Comment: @srijanshukla How will that work for the parent-child relationship here?

Comment: I think you should call `user.increment! :next_roll_number` before assigning it to **roll_number** in **students** table. And I hope you have wrapped the **create** in a transaction.

Comment: @Abhi I think that is where I am having issues. This is a callback function, so how can I wrap it in a transaction? Are you talking about the controller method `create`?

Comment: @Shobhit Yes, eg: `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
 Model1.find(74).increment! :count  
 Model2.create!()
end`

Here, **Model2** creation is going to fail due to validation error, so the increment will also rollback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work fine:

**Controller**

```
def create
  Student.transaction do
    Student.create(user_id: current_user, ...)
  end
end
```

**Student Model**

```
before_create :generate_roll_number

def generate_roll_number
  user.increment! :next_roll_number
  # Fires query like
  # UPDATE users SET next_roll_number=2, WHERE id=xxx

  self.roll_number = user.next_roll_number
end
```

Now, if any error happens while Student record is saved, the transaction will also rollback the incremented `next_roll_number` value in User table

Comment: Looks cool but why are you incrementing the roll number before assignment?

Comment: I was trying to suggest few pointers, which was not possible in comments **1>** By having that line before, you may not need to pre-initialize `next_roll_number` with 1, `increment!` will do it for `nil` as well. So, readability wise you know what value is going to be assigned to `roll_number`
**2>** The usage of transaction here